# Object detection and tracking with zed-2i camera

Tags: object-detection, yolov5, object-tracking, zed-sdk, stereolabs

i am new to the zed camera and my goal is to find and track the objects within the scene using zed-2i camera.also objects has to have a unique id and and their distance from the camera. can someone suggest me to right approach how it can be solved? my understanding is integrating zed with yolov5 might solve the problem ?

i am currently working on yolov5 custom detection example from git-hub (zed_examples). but still there is an dependency problem with the custom detection [here](https://community.stereolabs.com/t/zed-examples-yolov5-custom-detection-needs-update/1813). is here any alternative approach to track the objects along with their 3D information using Zed-2i.
Please do not hesitate to share your inputs.
Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming that you use the ZED SDK. there isn't a "stereolabs" tag yet.

Comment: Yes i am using ZED SDK